# How to stream Anorm large query results to client in chunked response with Play 2.5

Tags: scala, akka-stream, playframework-2.5, anorm

I have a pretty large result set (60k+ records columns) that I am pulling from a database and parsing with Anorm (though I can use play's default data access module that returns a ResultSet if needed). I need to transform and stream these results directly to the client (without holding them in a big list in memory) where they will then be downloaded directly to a file on the client's machine.

I have been referring to what is demonstrated in the Chunked Responses section in the [ScalaStream 2.5.x](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaStream) Play documentation. I am having trouble implementing the "getDataStream" portion of what it shows there.

I've also been referencing what is demoed in the Streaming Results and Iteratee sections in the [ScalaAnorm 2.5.x](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaAnorm) Play documentation. I have tried piping the results as an enumerator like what is returned here:

```
 val resultsEnumerator = Iteratees.from(SQL"SELECT * FROM Test", SqlParser.str("colName"))
```

into

```
val dataContent = Source.fromPublisher(Streams.enumeratorToPublisher(resultsEnumerator))
Ok.chunked(dataContent).withHeaders(("ContentType","application/x-download"),("Content-disposition","attachment; filename=myDataFile.csv"))
```

But the resulting file/content is empty.

And I cannot find any sample code or references on how to convert a function in the data service that returns something like this:

```
@annotation.tailrec
def go(c: Option[Cursor], l: List[String]): List[String] = c match {
  case Some(cursor) => {
    if (l.size == 10000000) l // custom limit, partial processing
    else {
      go(cursor.next, l :+ cursor.row[String]("VBU_NUM"))
    }
  }
  case _ => l
}

val sqlString = s"select colName FROM ${tableName} WHERE ${whereClauseStr}"

val results : Either[List[Throwable], List[String]] = SQL(sqlString).withResult(go(_, List.empty[String]))
results
```

into something i can pass to Ok.chunked().

So basically my question is, how should I feed each record fetch from the database into a stream that I can do a transformation on and send to the client as a chunked response that can be downloaded to a file?

I would prefer not to use Slick for this. But I can go with a solution that does not use Anorm, and just uses the play dbApi objects that returns the raw java.sql.ResultSet object and work with that.

Comment: There is no need to use converted `Iteratee` with Anorm/Play 2.5.x: https://github.com/playframework/anorm/blob/master/docs/manual/working/scalaGuide/main/sql/ScalaAnorm.md#akka-stream

Comment: @cchantep is correct that you want to use the Akka Streams support rather than Iteratees (in `anorm-akka` 2.5.2). Unfortunately some useful parts (e.g. getting a value on completion to allow you to close the DB connection) are still in Anorm 2.6.0-SNAPSHOT and not yet released.

Comment: Iteratee support is not better about resource management, so that doesn't change the point it's simpler to directly use the Akka support.

Comment: @cchantep I have tried using what is referenced in https://github.com/playframework/anorm/blob/master/docs/manual/working/scalaGuide/main/sql/ScalaAnorm.md#akka-stream. But I get an error when I try to pass the stream to Ok.chunked() saying:    Error during preStart in [anorm.AkkaStream$ResultSource@30ab92d8]
java.sql.SQLException: Connection is closed. Do you have and suggestions on what could solve this or how I should work with this stream?

Comment: @Elephantopus did you solve your *Connection is closed* issue? I have the same problem.

Comment: @Damian, Yes the code I provided in the answer below leaves the db connection open after the Source object has began streaming to client. The .alsoTo(Sink) takes care of closing the connection after all results have flowed through from the database. 

What is the issue you are having? Can you provide some sample code?

Comment: Please upvote this question if is relevant and helpful. I answered my question with the answer provided below. But I do not have enough reputation to mark it as the answer nor to upvote it.

Comment: @Elephantopus I have fixed my code already. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After referencing the [Anorm Akka Support](https://github.com/playframework/anorm/blob/master/docs/manual/working/scalaGuide/main/sql/ScalaAnorm.md#akka-stream) documentation and much trial and error, I was able to achieve my desired solution. I had to add these dependencies

```
"com.typesafe.play" % "anorm_2.11" % "2.5.2",
"com.typesafe.play" % "anorm-akka_2.11" % "2.5.2",
"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-stream" % "2.4.4"
```

to by build.sbt file for Play 2.5.

and I implemented something like this

```
//...play imports
import anorm.SqlParser._
import anorm._

import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{Sink, Source}

...

private implicit val akkaActorSystem = ActorSystem("MyAkkaActorSytem")
private implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

def streamedAnormResultResponse() = Action {
  implicit val connection = db.getConnection()

  val parser: RowParser[...] = ...
  val sqlQuery: SqlQuery = SQL("SELECT * FROM table")

  val source: Source[Map[String, Any] = AkkaStream.source(sqlQuery, parser, ColumnAliaser.empty).alsoTo(Sink.onComplete({
    case Success(v) =>
      connection.close()
    case Failure(e) =>
      println("Info from the exception: " + e.getMessage)
      connection.close()
  }))

  Ok.chunked(source)
}
```

Comment: Is it safe to use `alsoTo` like this @elephantopus. What we relly want to know is the completion of the stream right?. I would like to know if this approach has any side effect like performance issue etc.

Comment: Yes, it's only purpose is to close connection on completion of the stream, since it's asynchronous no impact on performance(that i've noticed). Though I haven't tested it thoroughly

Comment: If you streaming from Postgres, remember to:
1) set fetch size: `SQL("SELECT * FROM table").setFetchSize(Some(8192))`
2) set autocommit mode to false: `db.getConnection(autocommit = false)`

Otherwise, Postgres driver will start to buffer the whole result set.
https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/query.html#query-with-cursor